# set up secure connection over SSH

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

I'm setting up a server application which requires to establish a secure connection over SSH2, e.g. a client must open SSH2 connection to the server to reach specific application:

```
% ssh -s -p5000 my.server.com app
```

I want to understand, what exactly is happening after this command has completed? How client/server know that they have to run over SSH secure channel? Is this called ssh tunneling, or it has different name for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-s` flag tells `ssh` that instead of allocating a `tty` on the remote computer to use the subsystem specified as the remote command.  What you're doing is establishing an `ssh` session using `app` as the subsystem similar to how things would work if the remote subsystem were `sftp`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

All from your question is described pretty well in manual page for [`ssh(1)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1?query=ssh).

> `-s`
>
> May be used to request invocation of a subsystem on the remote system. Subsystems are a feature of the SSH2 protocol which facilitate the use of SSH as a secure transport for other applications (eg. sftp(1)). The subsystem is specified as the remote command.
>
> [...]
>
> `-p port`
>
> Port to connect to on the remote host. This can be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.